# How to 'shorten' \cline so that multiple groups in a table become visible?

Tags: tables, rules, tabularx

I would like to construct a table which looks like a `booktabs` table (but
without using the package `booktabs`). Instead of `\cmidrule`, I used `\cline`,
which comes pretty close (see below), but the lines drawn with `\cline` are too
wide, so that they touch... and therefore it's difficult for the eye to
determine where the groups start/end. Is there a solution to this? (without
using additional packages).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

% my trial with \cline
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
    \hline
    Sex & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Male} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Female} \\
    \cline{2-5} \cline{6-9}
    Age & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Child} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adult} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Child} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adult} \\
    \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9}
    {Class \ Survived} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} \\
    \hline
    1st & 0 & 5 & 118 & 57 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 140 \\
    2nd & 0 & 11 & 154 & 14 & 0 & 13 & 13 & 80 \\
    3rd & 35 & 13 & 387 & 75 & 17 & 14 & 89 & 76 \\
    Crew & 0 & 0 & 670 & 192 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 20 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

% with booktabs
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
    Sex & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Male} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Female} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
    Age & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Child} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adult} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Child} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adult} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    {Class \ Survived} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} & {No} & {Yes} \\
    \midrule
    1st & 0 & 5 & 118 & 57 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 140 \\
    2nd & 0 & 11 & 154 & 14 & 0 & 13 & 13 & 80 \\
    3rd & 35 & 13 & 387 & 75 & 17 & 14 & 89 & 76 \\
    Crew & 0 & 0 & 670 & 192 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 20 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
  \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}rrrrrrrrr@{}}
```

[image]

Comment: ... that's quite embarrassing I forgot that one :-) Thanks, David.

Comment: Is there a way to assign `\extracolsep` without setting the horizontal space between columns (or in this case before the first and to preserve symmetry after the last) to zero? `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}@{\kern\tabcolsep}rrrrrrrrr}`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yes you can use array package `!` instead of `@` it is the same except it doesn't remove the default space

Comment: What does the `@` do? What does the `{}` do?

Comment: @MartinThoma that is very basic latex syntax, probably best not to ask as a comment on a 4-year old question `@{zzz}` adds  `zzz` between the columns on each row.

Comment: And the last @{} is to set the extra column space to zero after the last column. I.e. the horizontal lines do not extend beyond the rightmost character of the rightmost column.

Comment: My sincere gratitudine for these four years in TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without widening the table? My table is already wide.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- set `\tabcolsep` to 3pt (instead of the default 6pt) to compensate